# How authoritative is the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: halacha-theory, jewish-books, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, kitzur-shulchan-aruch, authority

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch makes some clear statements that do not reflect the range of opinions. For example, Ch 53 #2, "...in the case of...vegetables, which are eaten after they are cooked, when the soup is also eaten, this is the halacha: over the soup you say borei pri ha'adamah, even if you do not eat the solid food." (See attached photo.)

To what extent is the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch considered authoritative?  How widely accepted is the KSA among ashkenazim?

[image: *Kitzur Shulcahn Aruch* book, open to chapter 53]

Comment: this is the opinion of the Rosh  And this is the halacha in bet yosef &  sa.  the reason is taste which is reached through cooking

Comment: What authority doesn't have positions that don't reflect the full range of opinions?

Comment: @DoubleAA Well, the Mishna Berura gives various opinions routinely.  It may be impossible to give the "full range" of opinions on many topics, but not giving the full range is different than giving one opinion and not even mentioning others.

Comment: One is called psak and one is called being a reference work. I thought you were asking about Poskim's psak being authoritative.

Comment: in this case Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim   205,  2 said this. על המים שבישלו בהם ירקות מברך הברכה עצמה שמברך על הירקות עצמן אף על פי שאין בהם אלא טעם הירק והני מילי כשבשלם בלא בשר אבל אם בישלם עם בשר מברך עליו שהכל: the same halacha exactly

Comment: may be perhaps an other example....

Comment: How exactly is anyone supposed to answer how authoritative it is? Seems primarily opinion based. Furthermore, as others have noted, the question appears to conflate authoritativeness with comprehensiveness.

Comment: @mevaqesh The one answer received so far seems to have addressed the question in a fashion I had hoped for.

Comment: @YehudaW That doesnt make your question a good question. It means you got lucky in receiving information you wanted in spite of doing a poor job specifying what you were looking for.

Comment: I was taught that if one is somewhere and they dont have their seforim with them an dthere is no one to ask then one can certainly rely on what the KSA says

Comment: @mevaqesh. How might I have worded the question differently

Comment: @YehudaW Why do you think that this opinion of the Kitzur might not be authoritative? Many many opinions (only some of which are brought in comments above) say that the broth gets a blessing based on what was cooked in it CYLOR

Answer (score 2):

My experience with the Kitzur is that many Chassidic groups consider it authoritive. The main exception to my knowledge is Chabad which relies on the Shulchan Aruch HaRav.

Comment: And until the Kitzur was translated into English, most of Lithuanian and north-Polish heritage followed the Chayei Adam more often than the Kitzur. In the 40s through 60s, my grandfather attended a shiur in the local Young Israel in Chayei Adam and Chokhmas Adam. (As well as Minchas Chinukh and Ein Yaakov; just to show how much the culture has changed in a historically short time.)

Answer (score 1):

In general the K.S.A. doesn't necessarily reflect accepted halacha in the sense that, for instance, the Mishna Brurah does. I don't think it's generally used by *poskim* when formulating a *psak*.  Many erroneously assume it's more authoritative because they understand the title to imply that it's just an abridged version of the Shulchan Aruch (when in fact the author, Rabbi Shlomo Gantzfried, often includes his own halachic opinions), and because it's a ubiquitous *sefer* due to its simplicity and great readability. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Ganzfried#Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch).

(This is not meant to insinuate that Rabbi Gantzfried was any less of a scholar than the authors of other works; it's only an observation about the degree to which K.S.A. is used today for *psak*. I also did not mean to imply that he was somehow wrong to include his own halachic opinions.)

Comment: `doesn't necessarily reflect accepted halacha in the sense that, for instance, the Mishna Brurah does.`  Do you mean ` I don't think it's generally used by poskim when formulating a psak` or something else? | FWIW R. Herschel Shachter strongly recommends the study of Kitzur over other Mishnah Berurah.

Answer (score 1):

R. [Hershel Shachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershel_Schachter) told me that in general, learning Kitzur Shulhan Arukh is preferable to learning Mishnah Berurah, for multiple reasons. One of which, is that it is clearer. The other relates to the Mishnah Berurah's propensity towards humra.