# Would talking to a friend about someone who is annoying to you be considered lashon hara?

Tags: mussar-ethics, lashon-hara-slander

I’ll expand the question in the title.

Suppose someone is being annoyed by somebody else or has certain doubts about how to proceed regarding somebody else’s behavior and is looking for advice. Not referring to any serious matter but definitely a cause for concern to them.

The question is twofold: Would asking for advice from a friend be permitted? Would they be allowed to simply talk about it in a cathartic way?

Would this incur in lashon hara, since it is certainly speech of an unwelcome or negatively seen behavior?

Of course, in the intent of not committing lashon hara you may assume that this person does not want to just communicate insults or exaggerate the situation, but merely report it as it is felt to them, as it is causing a moral burden or dilemma. However, my limited view of lashon hara would forbid this person from basically any kind of talking about somebody else, but I guess that point would be best approached in a separate post.

Thank you. Authoritative sources are especially appreciated.

I’m new to this site so apologies in advance if the tags are not appropriate.

Comment: If the purpose of asking the friend is constructive (letoelet), i.e. to obtain advice or clarification, can this be achieved without identifying the third party?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92705/170. najliel, does that page answer your question?

Comment: @msh210 I think it does. Thank you

Comment: @ShimonS Good point to keep in mind. Thanks