# Loshon Hora: Chafetz Chaim & Dissenting views

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, machlokes, chofetz-chaim

The sefer "Chofetz Chaim" is accepted worldwide as the leading authority in the Hilchos Shemiras Haloshon arena. However, as with every area in *halacha*, there are specific details which are subject to debate among the *poskim*. (See [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78652/17563), for example)

Can anyone cite examples (with sources, if possible) of contemporary Poskim who disagree with some of the Chofetz Chaim's conclusions - either *l'chumra* or *l'kula*?

Comment: The post you link to has.

Answer (score 4):

R. Yitzchak Yosef in [Yalkut Yosef Mo'adim 406:17](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=55401&st=&pgnum=655) rules that if one spoke Leshon Hara about his fellow, and the victim is unaware of this, he should not explicitly confess his sin to the victim, but instead should seek forgiveness from him in a general manner.

In the footnote, he notes that this ruling follows the opinion of R. S Z Auerbach (who himself quotes this in the name of R. Yisrael Salanter) and is not in accord with the opinion of [Chafetz Chaim Hilchot Leshon Hara 4:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Part_One%2C_The_Prohibition_Against_Lashon_Hara%2C_Principle_4.12.1?lang=bi), who ruled that the offender needs to explicitly tell the victim what he had said about him, before requesting forgiveness.